# What does this $\mathbb 1$ symbol in statistical learning theory mean?

Tags: statistics, notation

Searching for something I do not know the name of is hard...
Context is Statistical Learning Theory. Probably something basic, I do not remember from my boring statistics university lectures.
Without knowing how the symbol is called, I can only provide an image:

[image: Symbol I want to understad]

Comment: That's often used to denote the characteristic function.  Thus $\mathbb 1_S(x)=1$ iff $x\in S$, at it is $0$ if $x\not \in S$.

Comment: $\mathbb 1_{condition}$ is just a random variable which is $1$ if the condition is true and $0$ if it is false.

Comment: Related to characteristic/indicator functions, but expressed more probabilistically, in terms of a condition rather than a set. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: If you were to really write it in terms of indicator functions it would be: $$\mathbb E\left[\mathbb 1_{\{(x,y)\mid g(x)\neq y\}}(X,Y)\right]$$ which is a bit noisier. The book prefers a shorthand.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket

Comment: @lulu - I would prefer to call that an *indicator function* here since [*characteristic function* has another meaning in probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory))

Comment: @Henry  Fair point.  Though I doubt I can change 50 year old naming habits!  But I will try.

Comment: @Henry: In this case, I would prefer to call it an indicator random variable. It is, of course, an indicator function applied to a boolean random variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a set $X$ and a subset $S\subseteq X,$ the function $\mathbb 1_S$ is defined on $X$ as:

$$\mathbb 1_S(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in S\\0&x\not\in S\end{cases}$$

Here, in probability, the notation is simplified, where $\mathbb 1_C$ is defined for a condition $C$ as a random variable which is $1$ if $C$ is true, and $0$ if $C$ is not true.

So: $$\mathbb 1_{g(X)\neq Y}$$ is a shorthand for the set-notation version $$\mathbb 1_{\{(x,y)\mid g(x)\neq y\}}(X,Y),$$ an indicator function applied to random variables.

You can see how this notation would be an improvement even more clearly if you’re condition had $n$ variables like $$X_1^2+\cdots+ X_n^2<1.$$

Indicator functions let you talk about random events as random variables. In particular:

$$\mathbb E[\mathbb 1_C]=P(C).$$

Comment: So, the equation basically means, that the probability (risk) of a function g making a wrong prediction is equal to the mean of this indicator function, which is just wrong predictions divided by all predictions? (Y are the "true" labels and X are the inputs,)

Comment: Yes, $P(C)=E[\mathbb 1_C]$ for any condition $C.$ @Simon

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks. I can't give you any additional internet points in form of upvotes. I need 15 reputation to do so.